# How to compare HTTP_HOST with SERVER_NAME in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried the following but does not seem to work:

```
# IF HTTP_HOST != SERVER_NAME DO 403
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !%{SERVER_NAME} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a variable on RHS of `RewriteCond`. Use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^#]+)#(?!(www\.)?\1).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: thanks - how would I ensure the above does not consider www. in HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME to be a difference?

Comment: Be sure to have `UseCanonicalName On` activated (Off is default). Otherwise `%{SERVER_NAME}` would **not** take the Name from the ServerName entry from your VirtualHost, it would just always be the same as `%{HTTP_HOST}`, which was sent in the visitors request.